# Data schema for complex entities - which approach is simpler

Tags: database-design

I am reviewing a database model. I need some help with a part of the model. At this stage I'm just concerned with the logical model, not the implementation. I want to adopt a best practice.

**Summary of problem**

- The database is used by an app that manages legal cases for a law firm.
- Each case has multiple parties. (By party, I mean a some legal enity in the real world that has a stake in the case.)
- There are about 40 different types of parties.
- 2 of these types can be a single person, a single organisation, or multiple persons and/or organisations joined together in any combination.
- The other 38 types can be either a single person or a single organisation.
- Each case always has 2 parties of the complex types (i.e. potentially a combination of persons and organisations).
- Usually there are 5 to 10 parties in total per case.

**Options**

1. Each party is modelled as potentially a combintation of any number of persons and organisations. The tables would look like this:

   - Case `<`- CasePartyAssignment -`>` Party
     Where all parties are potentially a combination of persons and organisations:
   - Party `<-` PartyPersonAssignment `->` Person
   - Party `<-` PartyOrgAssignment `->` Organisation
2. Alternatively, I model this with 3 different types CasePartyAssignment tables.

   The first is the same as 1 above, which covers the complex scenario:

   - Case `<-` CaseComplexPartyAssignment `->` ComplexParty

     In addition I add specific tables for the simple scenarios:
   - Case `<-` CasePersonAssignment `->` Person
   - Case `<-` CaseOrgAssignment `->` Organisation

The way I see it, both options have advantages and disadvantages. For example, in option 1 I create a single way to store the data, which in itself is simple due to consistency. But that means I also model a party that I know is a simple Person using the PartyPersonAssignment designed to model the complex party.

Does anyone have any commnts/opinions about these options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think option 1 is more flexible.  With option 1, you'd be able to add or remove Persons or Organizations from a Party by adding or removing records from the many-to-many tables, whereas with option 2, if you start out with a simple single Person or single Organization setup, it is a little more clunky to modify it into a ComplexParty.  I guess I prefer to keep corner cases out of the data model, and try to just use a flexible model that can handle the corner cases in the same way as the more complex cases.

I don't think it's too bad to represent the single entity cases as a Party, even though the party is unnecessary in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll go ahead with option 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would model it a bit differently:

- Person
- Organisation
- PerOrg: super-type of Person/Organisation, i.e. a LegalEntity
- Party: either a complex party or a simple party
- PerOrgPartyAssignment: the relationship between PerOrg and Party, you can have either one or many PerOrgs per Party (but a minimum of one)
- Case: here you only have PlantiffParty and DefendentParty

The PerOrg concept (aka 'Anyone'/'Legal Entity'/'Party'...) is quite a powerful concept for any data models involving commercial relationships. I've used it a number of times and it always end up simplifying the data model when there are seemingly complex relationships.

Comment: In this model, I'm not sure about the details of the PerOrg super-type. If you mean a PerOrgId would be a non-mandatory FK on the Person and Organisation tables, that wouldn't work in our situation due to our need for a Person or Organisation to potentially join to more than one of these super types. Or did you mean PerOrg has columns PerOrgId, PersonId, OrgId? The latter is close to option 1, but I'm not sure what's better about doing it that way.

Comment: No, PerOrg it's a super-type. Supertype means that PerOrgID is the PK, not an FK. See http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/enterprise-solutions/understanding-entities-in-er-diagrams-14255 for examples of subtypes and supertypes